# How can I subclass gtest testing::Test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have test classes with some common functionality, and I want to create something like

```
class BaseTest : public testing::Test
```

then derive further subclasses, like

```
class StuffTest : public BaseTest
```

However, the compiler gives the error message

```
error: use of deleted function 'StuffTest::StuffTest()'
TEST_F(StuffTest, SFile)
```

How can I derive test subclass, and why this strange error message?

Added some test code:
(I want to add a test name in the subclasses. Without constructor, it works OK. With constructor I experience weird syntax errors.)

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

using namespace std;

// A new test class  of these is created for each test
class BaseTest
  : public testing::Test
{
public:
 // BaseTest(string a);
BaseTest();
   virtual void SetUp()
   { cerr << "Setting up " << MyName;}
   virtual void TearDown()
   {cerr << "Closing down " << MyName;}
protected:
  string MyName;
};


//BaseTest::BaseTest(string TestName)
BaseTest::BaseTest()
: testing::Test
{
//  MyName = TestName;
}

TEST_F(BaseTest, Tools)
{
  cerr << "Something was wrong\n";
}


// A new test class  of these is created for each test
class MyStuffTest : BaseTest
{
public:
};
/*
TEST_F(MyStuffTest, Tools)
{
  cerr << "Something was wrong\n";
}
*/


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
   return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: Show us complete definitions of classes `BaseTest` and `StuffTest`. Further sub-classing is perfectly legal, you must have made some mistake ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where you intended to call the constructors with
`std::string` arguments in the first place, usage of googletest fixture
classes does not imply explicit creation of fixture class objects.
The problem is that you are trying to create a fixture class
without a default constructor (it is not generated by the compiler
because you declared one with a `std::string` argument). This is
an issue because googletest creates a new class for each test declared
with `TEST_F(MyFixtureClass, ...)`, this new class inherits from
`MyFixtureClass` and needs the default constructor.

To obtain the name of the test, use `testing::TestInfo` object which can be retrieved using method `testing::UnitTest::current_test_info`. For a more detailed usage example, check [the documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#getting-the-current-tests-name).